# What happened to Katakuri's mouth?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece* episode 856 "The Forbidden Secret! Katakuri's Merienda!",
the cooks who bring Katakuri's lunch say that no one has ever seen Katakuri while he is eating, and her sister Brulee says that he has never once been on his back since he was born. But when Luffy breaks the house made of Mochi by Katakuri, it is seen that he was lying on his back and eating with his big mouth.

So, what happened to Katakuri's mouth that it is so big and horrifying? Why does he hide his mouth and also from everyone while he is eating? Why does he murder the cooks when he is exposed by Luffy?

Relevant YouTube video: [Katakuri True Face, Luffy Exposes Him](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suRoOfPNG-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What happened to Katakuri's mouth?** It was [due to his fast eating habits](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Katakuri#Past) that caused his mouth to greatly expand. I'm no medical expert so I'm not sure if this is possible in real life.

**Why does he hide his mouth?** Mostly due to **insecurity** (I mean, if it were me, I'd probably also hide my mouth). As stated in the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Katakuri#Personality), he is very sensitive to the point that he would attack anyone who sees his mouth.

**He also hides himself from everyone while he is eating.** Because he is gluttonous and seems to value his snack time greatly. From the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Katakuri#Personality), it is stated that:

> ...Katakuri is extremely private about his eating habits, as he is extremely gluttonous and slovenly, talking to himself in ecstasy about the quality of the food. He loves donuts and enjoys gorging on them since childhood. For this reason, he eats his snacks in solitude, and this is the only time he uncovers his mouth...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in [Charlotte Katakuri](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Katakuri)

According to this,

> Katakuri consciously tries to maintain his noble appearance as a
>   person who is not glutinous and lazy. His attempt at keeping up his
>   appearance is good to the point where nobody ever sees him acting
>   without manners.

Also in the next paragraph it is said that,

> Katakuri is insecure about showing his mouth to anyone since he was
>   bullied as a child for showing his mouth around his family. He prefers
>   to cover it up in most of his appearances.

Comment: The answer is so... so... much better than that quote implies.  The "bullies" teased him but he didn't give a s#*+.  He terrified them and they were pathetic compared to him.  They took their revenge out on Brulee, however, giving her that iconic scar.  He massacred them in response but covers his face to reduce further drama.